# pandas: How to merge rows into single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which contains names and numbers in multiple rows as shown in picture.[image]

I want to merge rows with name into header and rows with numbers into row0. What I mean is I want 世田谷, 渋谷... at next to 大田 as header and also numbers at row0.
Here is what I have tried but still dose not work.
Thank you in advance.

`df1 = df.iloc[0:1]`

`df2 = df.iloc[1:3]`

`df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`
[image]

Comment: Are the rows with numbers always the odd rows, or could they be in any row?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the index ofdf2 is not matching with the index of df1.
So, concat adds the df2 rows as per the index as third row.
Reset the index of df2 before concat will fix your issue.

```
df1 = df.iloc[0:1]

for i in range(1,(len(df.index)),2):
    df2 = df.iloc[i:i+2]
    df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
    df2.columns = list(df2.iloc[0,:])
    df2 = df2.drop(0,axis=0)
    df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df1
```

Comment: This wouldn't get the column names aligned though!

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. It worked for me. Pls test now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],['d','e','f'],[4,5,6],['g','h','i'],[7,8,9]],columns=['a','b','c'])

df = df.T
_df = df[0]
for i in df.columns:
  if i%2 == 1:
    df2 = df[i+1]
    df2.index = df[i].values
    _df = pd.concat([_df, df2])
_df = _df.reset_index()
df1 = _df.T
df1.columns = _df['index']
df1 = df1[df1.index==0]
df1
```

Also, used `df.T` because it's just gonna be looping over `df.columns` and picking up the odd rows (as it seems from your data!)

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want the data frame to contain only one row(which contains all the numbers) and the letters/words will act as corresponding column names for the numerical values.

```
df=pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

new_df=pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[0].to_list()],columns=df.columns)
for x in range(int((df.shape[0]-1)/2)):
    sample_df=pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[2*(x+1)].to_list()],columns=df.iloc[2*x+1].to_list())
    new_df=pd.concat([new_df,sample_df ],axis=1)
```

This should work. Basically I am creating a new data frame and concating it to the previous dataframe in the loop. let me know if you face any difficulties.